# SSRS Hide text not text box on toggle

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have created a report that has a text field that is pretty substantial, and when brought into the SSRS report give a large text box. So to combat this I have created a preview field like so :

[image]

and I have set the description column to hide with a toggle on Preview...

[image]

What I'm attempting to achieve is to hide the preview text when the description is visable. I've done it by hiding the text box in the text box properties but it removes the borders...
[image]

What I want to do is just hide the text in the box and not the box itself. Is it possible to do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative would be to place the descriptions elsewhere in the report and then use a link so that when the preview is clicked on, the report jumps to the description.

In the tablix with the descriptions change the bookmark field to the field with the previews e.g.

```
=Fields!Preview.Value
```

In the tablix with the previews go to the textbox with the preview, select 'Text Box Properties' and select go to bookmark

[image: Text Box Properties Go To Bookmar]

In Select Bookmark put

```
=Fields!Preview.Value
```

You will then be able to get to the description by clicking on the preview.

Comment: couldnt find a suitable solution but this was clever thinking